# How to find the trace of exponential of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

> Given $$A=\begin{bmatrix}-3&2\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ how to find $e^{trA}$?

$e^A=pe^Dp^{-1}$ where p is invertible matrix and D is diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigen value of A. Should i proceed with this concept. Please suggest me.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Yes I know it is $(A-\lambda I)*x$ where X is eigen vector

Comment: You shouls diagonalize the $A$, so it will be something like this: $VBU$, where $B$ is diagonal. And then, apply the function to the diagonal elements of $B$, and finish the multiplication.

Comment: And the trace of A is just $-3$.

Comment: @Botond Knowing $A=VBU$ where $B$ is diagonal doesn't help; it's crucial that $U=V^{-1}$. (Because $\exp(VBV^{-1})=V\exp(B)V^{-1}$.)

Comment: Pls explain me in answer box detail I don't get it clearly and trace of A is -3; is $e^{traceA}$ is -3 also

Comment: Yes @DavidC.Ullrich, I assumed that he knows that.

Comment: The trace is just the sum of the elements in the diagonal. So it's just a number.

Comment: I want answer in the box I can't get ur clue How to find exponential of A

Comment: @Botond "You shouls diagonalize the A" This is not necessary.

Comment: @Did yes. And you can also use projector decomposition (I'm not sure about the name)

Comment: @Botond Why suggest full diagonalization then? Implying it is "necessary", even...

Comment: @Did the diagonalization is the easiest way. To calculate the projectors, you need to do tensor product, and I'm not sure if he knows that. Also, finding some pattern in the minimal polinomial is not easy every time. I did not have enough time to check your answer completely, but I think I haven't seen this method before.

Comment: @Botond To sum up, diagonalization is easier than a method using projectors which you cannot remember. Good to know, but this says nothing about diagonalization vs the method with no diagonalization in my answer (which does not even require to evaluate any product of $2\times2$ matrices, except $A\cdot I=A$). Anyway, by all means, please take your time to "check" this...

Comment: @Did I will definitely check your answer later, but I don't have enough time now.

Comment: @Botond Sorry but should I feel concerned?

Comment: @Did What do you mean? I can't understand it.

Comment: When I read the question, how to find $e^{tr A}$, for me it's simply $e^{-3}$ and I wouldn't write answers as seen below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short route, which avoids unneeded diagonalizations, is to compute every exponential of $A$, that is, to look for functions $x$ and $y$ such that, for every $t$, $$e^{tA}=x(t)A+y(t)I$$ Then, $\mathrm{tr}(A)=-3$ and $\det(A)=2$ hence $$A^2=-3A-2I$$
This implies $$x'(t)A+y'(t)I=(e^{tA})'=Ae^{tA}=A(x(t)A+y(t)I)=x(t)(-3A-2I)+y(t)A$$ that is, $$x'(t)A+y'(t)I=(y(t)-3x(t))A-2x(t)I$$ or, equivalently, $$x'(t)=y(t)-3x(t)\quad y'(t)=-2x(t)$$ This implies that $$x''(t)+3x'(t)+2x(t)=0$$ The roots of the polynomial $t^2+3t+2=(t+2)(t+1)$ are $-1$ and $-2$ hence $$x(t)=ue^{-t}+ve^{-2t}$$ for some given constants $(u,v)$, which implies $$y(t)=x'(t)+3x(t)=2ue^{-t}+ve^{-2t}$$ The initial conditions $x(0)=0$ and $y(0)=1$, when applied to these formulas for $x(0)$ and $y(0)$, yield $u=1$ and $v=-1$, hence, for every $t$, $$e^{tA}=(e^{-t}-e^{-2t})A+(2e^{-t}-e^{-2t})I$$ that is, $$e^{tA}=\begin{pmatrix}-e^{-t}+2e^{-2t} & 2e^{-t}-2e^{-2t}\\-e^{-t}+e^{-2t}&2e^{-t}-e^{-2t}\end{pmatrix}$$ from which the value of the matrix $e^{3A}$ follows.

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: Excellent! Why would the decomposition $\mathrm{e}^{tA}=x(t)A+y(t)I$ in general ? Is it true in higher dimension ?

Comment: @deque Indeed, for $d\times d$ matrices, using the notation $A^0=I$ and considering the characteristic polynomial $$\chi_A(t)=\det(xI-A)=\sum_{k=0}^da_kt^k$$ the same approach is valid, using the fact that $e^{tA}$ is a linear combination of the $d$ matrices $I$, $A$, ..., $A^{d-1}$, that is, $$e^{tA}=\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}x_k(t)A^k$$ where each $x_k(t)$ solves the differential equation $$\sum_{k=0}^da_kx^{(k)}(t)=0$$

Comment: For $d=2$, this reads $$e^{tA}=x(t)A+y(t)I$$ where $x(0)=0$, $y(0)=1$ and  $$x'(t)=y(t)+\mathrm{tr}(A)x(t)\quad y'(t)=-\det(A)x(t)$$ hence $$x''(t)-\mathrm{tr}(A)x'(t)+\det(A)x(t)=0=y''(t)-\mathrm{tr}(A)y'(t)+\det(A)y(t)$$

Comment: @Did "using the fact that $e^{tA}$ is a linear combination of the $d$ matrices $I, A, ..., A^{d−1}$":    Why is this the case ?  I agree that $e^{tA}$ is a polynomial in $A$ (by closedness of the set of polynomials in A), but did you assume the matrix nilpotent ?

Comment: @deque "did you assume the matrix nilpotent ?" Of course not. "Why is this the case ?" Keyword: Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: @Did Got it! Is it because $A^d$ is a linear combination of the lower powers and therefore we can write every $A^{d+k}$ as a lin. combination of $I,A,...,A^{d−1}$ ?

Comment: @deque This technique is a consequence of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem and works for any analytic function.

Comment: @amd "and works for any analytic function" Hmmm... Here one uses the fact that $u(t)=e^{tA}$ solves $u'(t)=Au(t)$. More generally, if $v(t)=e^{tP(A)}$ for some polynomial $P$, then $v'(t)=P(A)v(t)$ hence the technique works using the Euclidean division of $P$ by $\chi_A$, but if $w(t)=e^{tG(A)}$ for some non polynomial $G$, then $w'(t)=G(A)w(t)$, and how to pursue?

Comment: @Did Basically, formal division of the power series. Valid only where everything converges, of course. See, for example, http://web.mit.edu/2.151/www/Handouts/CayleyHamilton.pdf for a sketch. The matrix exponential is a special case of this.

Comment: @amd Right. The source passes over some details when the minimal polynomial is different from the characteristic polynomial, but one sees the idea. Thanks.

Comment: @Did They cover that case to some degree when they talk about repeated eigenvalues at the end. You need to differentiate a few times to generate more independent equations.

Answer (score 1):

For a $2\times2$ matrix $A$ that has distinct real eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ there’s a shortcut that takes advantage of the decomposition $$A=\lambda_1P_1+\lambda_2P_2 = \lambda_1{A-\lambda_2I\over\lambda_1-\lambda_2}+\lambda_2{A-\lambda_1I\over\lambda_2-\lambda_1}.$$ $P_1$ and $P_2$ are projections onto the respective eigenspaces that have the property $P_1P_2=P_2P_1=0$. Since for any projection $P$, $P^2=P$ this means that $$A^k = \lambda_1^k{A-\lambda_2I\over\lambda_1-\lambda_2}+\lambda_2^k{A-\lambda_1I\over\lambda_2-\lambda_1}$$ and $$e^{tA} = e^{\lambda_1t}{A-\lambda_2I\over\lambda_1-\lambda_2}+e^{\lambda_2t}{A-\lambda_1I\over\lambda_2-\lambda_1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the eigendecomposition of $A$, that is, $A=P\Lambda P^{-1}$ where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ of $A$ and $P$ is a matrix whose columns are the orthogonalized eigenvectors of $A$.

Then, $e^A$ is computed as $e^A=Pe^\Lambda P^{-1}$ (mentioned [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Diagonalizable_case)) where $$e^\Lambda =\begin{bmatrix} e^{\lambda_1} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{\lambda_2} \end{bmatrix}.$$ Since you want to compute $e^{9A}$, note that $9A=P(9\Lambda)P^{-1}$, so $e^{9A}=Pe^{9\Lambda}P^{-1}$.

For $e^{\text{trace}(A)}$, note that $\text{trace}(A)=-3$ is just a number so $e^{\text{trace}(A)} =e^{-3}$.